# How to read from mysql and write column wise in csv file?

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

I have different tables in a database(say mysql). i need to extract some columns from different table and write it in a csv file. consider table 1

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
table 2       table 3
X 7           AB A1
Y 8           BC B2
Z 10          CD C3
U 11          DE D4
V 12          
W 13
```

i want to write 1st column from table 1,2nd col from table 2, and 1st col from table 3 in a csv file such that empty rows are made null.

```
output: 
A,7,AB
B,8.BC
C,10,CD
null,11,DE
null,12,null
null,13,null
```

i can do the basic reading and writing from mysql to csv, need help in the logic or code to get the above output. "Looking for a generic solution for say 'n' number of columns from 'n' number of tables". above is jus a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how you read your database but assume you do it with JDBC:

```
    ResultSet tableAReusltSet= null;
    ResultSet tableBReusltSet= null;
    ResultSet tableCReusltSet= null;
    List<PseudeContainer> container = new ArrayList<>();
    while (tableAReusltSet.next()) { 
        PseudeConteiner ps = new PseudoContainer();
        ps.col1 = tableAReusltSet.getString("ColumnName");
        container.add(ps);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (tableBReusltSet.next()) { 
        if(container.size() <= i){
             container.add(new PseudeContainer());
        }
        container.get(i).col2 = tableBReusltSet.getString("ColumnName");
    }

    i = 0;
    while (tableBReusltSet.next()) { 
        if(container.size() <= i){
             container.add(new PseudeContainer());
        }
        container.get(i).col2 = tableBReusltSet.getString("ColumnName");
    }
```

//.. now you have a collection to work with which you can write

```
public PseudeContainer {
    String col1 = null;
    String col2 = null;
    String col3 = null;

}
```

Above should work.. still pseudo code...

Comment: thnx for the pseudo code. i'm looking for a generic soluntion. there can be "n" number of columns not necessarily 3 columns.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but your initial question did not mention an explicit column number. Anyway the above solution can be used for that as well. Just put in the PseudeContainer class a List<String> which represents the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the logic here is some pseudo code that may help you in whatever language you are using. Since I don't know how you are exporting to csv I made it pretty generic.

```
arr1 = select column1 from table1;
arr2 = select column2 from table2;
arr3 = select column1 from table3;
max = isBigger(arr1.length, arr2.length);
max = isBigger(max, arr3.length);
for(i=0; i<max; i++)
{
 if(arr1[i]=="") arr1[i]=null;
 if(arr2[i]=="") arr2[i]=null;
 if(arr3[i]=="") arr3[i]=null;
 print arr1[i] + "," + arr2[i] + "," + arr3[i];
}
```

Comment: thnx for the pseudo code. i'm looking for a generic soluntion for "n" number of columns not necessarily 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend **3rd party libraries** to handle CSV files:

[Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

[Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)